# Laplace transform of $t^n$ using integration by parts

Tags: indefinite-integrals, laplace-transform

I am trying to solve the following question:

> Let n be a positive integer. Show that $\mathcal{L(t^n)(s)=\frac{n}{s}} \mathcal{L(t^{n-1})}$ and use mathematical induction to prove $\mathcal{L(t^n)(s)=\frac{n!}{s^{n+1}}}$ for every positive integer $n$.

How would I go about doing this? I am not sure how to manipulate the indefinite integral or use the Laplace transform to get the result. I tried to begin by using the derivative of a Laplace transform, but ended up in a loop.

Any guidance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can use the Laplace transform od a  derivative  or integrate by part...for part a of the exercice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question title says it: Integrate by parts.
$$\int_{a}^{b}u dv = uv|_{a}^{b}- \int_{a}^{b} vdu$$
Let $u = t^n$, so $dv = e^{-st}dt$, and so $du = nt^{n-1}dt$ while $$v = \frac{e^{-st}}{-s}$$
The limit of the $uv$ term as $t \rightarrow 0$ and as $t \rightarrow \infty$ are both $0$.  Now look at what you have left:
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{s}nt^{n-1}e^{-st} dt$$
Pull out constants and you have it.

Answer (score 3):

$$\mathcal{L}(t\mapsto t^n)(s)=\int_0^\infty \underbrace{t^n}_{u}\underbrace{e^{-st}\mathrm{d}t}_{\mathrm{d}v}=(uv)|^\infty_0-\int_0^\infty v~\mathrm{d}u$$
$$=\left(-\frac{1}{s}t^ne^{-st}\right)\Bigg|^\infty_0+\dots$$
Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

$$\mathcal{L}(t^n)(s)=\frac{n}{s}\mathcal{L(t^{n-1})}$$
You can integrate by part or you can use the Laplace transform of a derivative:
$$s\mathcal{L}(t^n)(s)= \mathcal{L}{(nt^{n-1})}$$
$$s\mathcal{L}(t^n)(s)= \mathcal{L}\{(t^{n})'\}$$
$$s\mathcal{L}(t^n)(s)-0= \mathcal{L}\{(t^{n})'\}$$
This is just:
$$ \mathcal{L}\{y'\}=s\mathcal{L}(y)-y(0)$$
Where $y(t)=t^n$